# How to get total number of documents in Marklogic database?

Tags: marklogic

I have around 20 lacs documents in Marklogic Database. I want the total number of documents in my search application for pagination. For getting the totals I am using

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), $query))
```

where $query is the combination of various queries combined in `cts:and-query`.  But I am not getting the correct total. When $query is blank it shows much higher count than the total number of documents in the database. When I use

```
xdmp:estimate(doc())
```

it shows me the correct total but it would be static total which would not change according to the query. I want the total according to the results returned in response to a particular query that's why I passed $query as an argument but it is not showing correct total. `fn:count()` shows correct total but when the number of documents are around 20 lacs then `fn:count()` does not work because `fn:count()` is slower than `xdmp:estimate()`.

Please help me to get the correct total number of documents returned in response to the search term entered by the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand what is going on here, start by reading the architecture whitepaper from http://resources.marklogic.com/library/media/inside-marklogic

Now try this test case:

```
xdmp:estimate(doc()),
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), ()))
```

The first expression will count the number of *documents* in the database. The second expression will count the number of *document fragments* in the database. So if the results are different, you probably have fragment roots or fragment parents configured. Some special documents also create extra fragments: I think spelling dictionaries and thesaurus documents do this.

If you want to restrict the estimate to XML document roots, specify the document root QName(s) in the searchable expression, or use `/*` if you do not care about the root element name.

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(/*, ()))
```

You could also use the cts:query argument to specify a QName that only appears in the documents you want to count.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. Do you want the total number of documents in the database OR the total number of documents matching your search?

`xdmp:estimate` is the right way to go but it is only an **ESTIMATE**. IF the query used in the estimate can be completely resolved from indexes then the estimate will be 100% correct. However, if the query can't be resolved completely from indexes (requires filtering) then estimate will be off by some amount. This is because `xdmp:estimate` only uses the indexes to give you a count. Compare `fn:count(cts:search(doc(), $query))` to `xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), $query))`. If the results are significantly different for a given query then you either need to turn on additional indexing to support that query or live with the difference.