# How to get list of document uri names from a database marklogic?

Tags: xml, database, xquery, marklogic, xquery-sql

Hey I am trying to get the list of all document names /uri from a given MarkLogic database.

I found this line in stackoverflow:
[How to get total number of documents in Marklogic database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654431/how-to-get-total-number-of-documents-in-marklogic-database)

...which will get the count of documents in a database.  I'm not sure how to modify this to list all document URIs.

Also given a document URI I wanted to see if it exists in the database?

I tried the following, but couldn't achieve the same

```
for $x in xdmp:directory("/myDirectory/", "1")
return
fn:document-uri($x)
```

I need a Xquery command just like this. I am new to marklogic, can someone help me on this?

Comment: Tip: try to ask one question at a time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fn:doc() will return a list of all documents if no parameter is given, or return the document if a URI is given.  So to list all URIs in a database, use:

```
for $x in fn:doc()
   return fn:document-uri($x)
```

See [fn:doc](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:doc?q=fn:doc&v=8.0&api=true) for more.  If you want to check whether a document exists, just use `fn:doc()` with a URI:

```
fn:doc("/example/uri.xml")
```

Comment: i found another function to check if the document exists

Comment: This approach loops through all the documents, reads them, then calls a function for each. Tyler's answer is much more efficient.

Comment: This is the only way I found to list all documents from a MarkLogic database. It works in the ML's `queryconsole`. I am just starting out and I needed this to test something. Thank You!

Answer (score 10):

If all you need to get from the database is the list of uri use [`cts:uris()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris). It will just return the uri and won't require the full documents to be return like [`fn:doc()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:doc) would. If the uri lexicon is set to true at the database level the it will just be going off on in an memory index.

If you want to check if a document exists use

[`fn:doc-available("uri of document")`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:doc-available)

Comment: Yes I did thanks. Updated the answer with the correct name. I was using the phone app and was doing it from memory.

Answer (score 4):

1- If you have used collection then you can use

`for $each in collection("collection-name")
return fn:document-uri($each)`

2- If you have same directory structure then use

`for $each in xdmp:directory("/myDirectory/", "infinity")
return fn:document-uri($each)`

3- If you have not used any of the above case, you can use `cts:uris()`
Please note in order to use `cts:uris(), URI Lexicon` needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to find if the document exists:

```
xdmp:exists(doc("uri.xml"))
```

Comment: This works, but beware that this creates a URI lock. Very useful when you need to check if a uri already exists when creating new documents.